# Issue with gmail response i am getting

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to get a response from gmail but my response i getting like this `Status=Moved Temporarily, StatusCode=302` i am not able to understand what i am getting wrong with the url i am passing. This is the url i am using

```
auth_uri = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?  
scope= https://mail.google.com&
redirect_uri='my redict url'&
client_id='my client id'&
response_type=code&
approval_prompt=force&
login_hint='+login_hint;
```

When i try to use the generated url on browser from the response from google i have been redirected to [image]

this page. Please tell me what is getting wrong with this url or what i need to add and anything else i need to do please guide me to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What is your redirect URI? "my redirect url"? That is not valid. You need to give a valid URI. I am using

> `http://localhost:8080/`

This is the URI oAuth will redirect after authorization.

Comment: I changed my redirect url but still getting the same response from google. My redirect url which i was using before was 'https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox' This is the page from where i am sending request.

Comment: Did you update the client_secret.json file after changing the URI?

Answer (score 0):

Is your redirect URL in the list of whitelisted URLs in the developers console for your project?

Comment: yes the url which i have mentioned above please let me know what might be the reason i am getting this issue.